# JavaScript - getElementById doesn't work on specific page

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I want to automate clicking the agree button to Google's cookie policies.
(I clean cookies after closing a tab, and I don't want to create a google account, so I get asked every time I use google)

There is a div element with the ID "introAgreeButton" that I'm trying to access with my script:

```
<div role="button" id="introAgreeButton" [...]></div>
```

However, document.getElementById('introAgreeButton') always returns null.

My first thought was that the element wasn't loaded by the time my function was executed. But it doesn't work if I execute it on window.onload, or even if I run it in a loop until the element is definitely there:

```
window.onload = function() {  
  var x = document.getElementById('introAgreeButton')
  console.log(x)
}
```

Output:
`null`

```
function loop() { 
  var x = document.getElementById('introAgreeButton')  
  if (x) {
    console.log('success')
  } else {
    loop()
  }
}
```

Output:
`null`
`null`
`null`
...

Can be tested on https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=test

Anyone have an idea why this is and how to solve it?

Edit: I execute the script via the browser extension TamperMonkey

Comment: I assume this is executed from within the context of an extension?

Comment: @JustinTaddei Yes, I execute it with TamperMonkey

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the element is not on the other side of a document boundary?

Comment: @JustinTaddei: Actually no, how could I check this?

Comment: The chrome's inspector panel, find the element on the page and check the "element path" (I'm not sure of the official name) at the bottom. It looks kind of like "html>body>div.something>etc". What you're looking for is something in that path is labeled "#document". It will also show up in the element tree under the same name. Let me know if you have any trouble figuring out what I mean :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use setInterval to check if element is rendered in DOM like this :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var intervalID = null;

    function checkElementInDOM () {
        var element = document.getElementById('introAgreeButton');
    
        if (element) {
            clearInterval(intervalID);

            // DO YOUR STUFF HERE ...
        }
    }

    intervalID = setInterval(checkElementInDOM, 100);
});
```

To be used intelligently, however, so as not to have a setInterval which works continuously. Maybe think about adding a maximum number of attempts.